# Schedule a periodic task dependent on result of previous run

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, scheduled-tasks

I need to execute a task every `X` seconds.
I know that I could use a `TimerTask` or `ScheduledThreadPool` but my problem is that this task depends on state.
I.e. what the task will do in run `B` depends on what was the result of run `A`.
What would be the best approach to code this?
Doing perhaps a

```
while(true){  
  //do stuff  
  Thread.sleep(5000);  
}
```

is the best I can do here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just define your state in your TimerTask implementation and then use `Timer`:

```
TimerTask task = new TimerTask ()
{
    private int state = 0;

    @Override
    public void run ()
    {
        System.out.println ("State is: " + state);
        state += 1;
    }
};

new Timer ().schedule (task, 0L, 1000L);
```

This will run task every second (every 1000L milliseconds) forever.

Comment: I need to run it "forever" every X seconds

Comment: So it just calls `run` all the time?It does not recreate the runnable?

Comment: @Jim In my example `run` is called every second forever on the same instance of `TimerTask`.  Just run and see.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use a `Timer` with a `TimerTask`:

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Some task
    }
};
timer.schedule(task, 10000, 10000);
```

Which runs the `task` every `10s` starting after an initial first time delay of `10s`.

As per the documentation of [`Timer.schedule`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html#schedule%28java.util.TimerTask,%20long,%20long%29), this method

> Schedules the specified task for repeated fixed-delay execution,
>   beginning after the specified delay. Subsequent executions take place
>   at approximately regular intervals separated by the specified period.